# Complicated old php MySQL query in Laravel Elequent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-8

I am working on an old complicated MySql query and I need to write this in Laravel Elequent.

```
    SELECT count(relation.id) as amount, 
    IF (relation.type!=2,YEAR(NOW()) - YEAR(if (`relation`.`birthday`=0,null,`relation`.`birthday`)) - (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '00-%m-%d') < DATE_FORMAT(`relation`.`birthday`, '00-%m-%d')),null) as age
    FROM relation
    WHERE (`relation`.`stopdate` IS NULL OR `relation`.`stopdate`>'2021-10-04')
    GROUP BY age 
    ORDER BY age
```

I have tried different ways. For example the Elequent below works fine

```
Relation::Relation::selectRaw("COUNT('relation.id') AS amount")
->selectRaw("IF (relation.type!=2,YEAR(NOW()) - YEAR(if (`relation`.`birthday`=0,null,`relation`.`birthday`)) - (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '00-%m-%d') < DATE_FORMAT(`relation`.`birthday`, '00-%m-%d')),null) as age")
    ->where(function ($q) {
                $q->whereNull('relation.stopdate')
                    ->orWhere('relation.stopdate', '>', Carbon::now());
            })
    ->get();
```

but how can I write this part completely in Elequent without selectRaw()?

```
->selectRaw("IF (relation.type!=2,YEAR(NOW()) - YEAR(if (`relation`.`birthday`=0,null,`relation`.`birthday`)) - (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '00-%m-%d') < DATE_FORMAT(`relation`.`birthday`, '00-%m-%d')),null) as age")
```

Comment: I don't think you can since you're not using simple select statements.

Comment: Eloquent is not ment for statistics queries, you can use it for statistics but it wont make much difference if you still use variable binding

Comment: Can I write this query in a way that everything is elequent?